# How to summary selected columns?

Tags: r

Here is the data frame.

```
Number UrinateFrequently  UrgeUrinate
1      occasionally       rarely
2      rarely             rarely
3      occasionally       occasionally
4      rarely             always
5      frequently         always
```

I can only summarise one column at a time like this

```
a %>% group_by(UrinateFrequently) %>% summarise(n = n())

 UrinateFrequently     n
  <fct>             <int>
1 rarely                2
2 occasionally          2
3 frequently            1
```

How can I summary all all of them at a time like this?

```
               UrinateFrequently  UrgeUrinate
rarely               x                 x
occasionally         x                 x
frequently           x                 x
always               x                 x
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
a %>% summarise(across(everything(),list(group_by(.),n = n(.))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

a %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Number) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = value, names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

**Output**

```
  value        UrgeUrinate UrinateFrequently
  <chr>              <int>             <int>
1 always                 2                 0
2 occasionally           1                 2
3 rarely                 2                 2
4 frequently             0                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the unique items in the two columns are not the same and you want a common data basis, then first convert to a 'factor' data type with a common set of levels: The use `sapply` with `table`

```
 df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1] , factor, levels=unique(unlist(df[-1])) ) )
 #---------------------
 sapply(df[-1], table)
 #----------------
             UrinateFrequently UrgeUrinate
occasionally                 2           1
rarely                       2           2
frequently                   1           0
always                       0           2
```

I'm "old school" with R, so tidyverse functions are not the first tool I reach for. As a wild-ass guess you might want to try package:purrr for its `map` function(s).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:3) %>% 
  count(name, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = 0L)
```

**Output**

```
  value        UrgeUrinate UrinateFrequently
  <chr>              <int>             <int>
1 always                 2                 0
2 occasionally           1                 2
3 rarely                 2                 2
4 frequently             0                 1
```

---

Another alternative:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

imap(df[,2:3], ~ as.data.frame(table(., dnn = "Response"), responseName = .y)) %>% 
  reduce(full_join) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ coalesce(., 0)))
```

**Output**

```
      Response UrinateFrequently UrgeUrinate
1   frequently                 1           0
2 occasionally                 2           1
3       rarely                 2           2
4       always                 0           2
```